# How do I fix this list index out of range error?

Tags: python, list, range

I'm trying to go through a txt file to pull out certain numbers, store them in a list, and then use the numbers to pull out strings stored in the same file. My code works on some of my files, but I'm suddenly getting a list index out of range error.

Here is an example of the portion of the text file im trying to get out

```
                     /note="tRNA-Arg2"
     tRNA            5573494..5573567
                     /locus_tag="Tery_R0035"
                     /product="tRNA-Arg"
```

or

```
     tRNA            complement(5630800..5630872)
                     /locus_tag="Tery_R0036"
                     /product="tRNA-His"
```

I'm trying to get the numbers that are written after tRNA.

Here's my code to extract the numbers into a list:

```
def extract_numbers(line):
    #empty list
    numbers = []
    #creates a buffer (temporary space)
    digits = ""
    #for character in the line
    for c in line:
        #if its a digit
        if c.isdigit():
            #add character to the buffer
            digits += c
        #if it isnt a number
        else:
            #if there is something in the buffer (ie its not 0)
            if len(digits) > 0:
                #add the buffer to the numbers list
                numbers.append(digits)
                #empty again
                digits = ""
    #to make sure the last number is added to the list
    if len(digits) > 0:
        numbers.append(digits)
    return numbers
```

and to use the last function to write this over the file itself

```
def extract_tRNA(path):
    with io.open(path, mode="r", encoding="utf-8") as file:
        genome = file.readlines()
        start_stop = []
        for line in genome:
            if "tRNA" in line[0:21]:
                numbers = extract_numbers(line[21:])
                start_stop.append((int(numbers[0]), int(numbers[1])))
        return start_stop
```

then, I run it with this:

```
work_dir = "/Users/..."
for path in glob.glob(os.path.join(work_dir, "*.gbff")):

    sequences = extract_seq(path)
    tRNA_loc = extract_tRNA(path)
    extract_genes(path, tRNA_loc, sequences)
    print(path)
```

Is it my file or code? I'm also not sure if there is an easier way to do the same thing?

Thanks for any help!

UPDATE trying regex:

```
work_dir = "where my files are"
for path in glob.glob(os.path.join(work_dir, "*.gbff")):
    with io.open(path, mode="r", encoding="utf-8") as file:
        genome = file.readlines()
        for line in genome:
            if "tRNA" in line[0:21]:
                p = re.compile('\d+')  # \d means digit and + means one or more
                m = p.findall(line)
        print(m)
```

Comment: For your first number, the string is `5573494..5573567`. Did you want the tRNA to be one big number, `55734945573567` or a list of numbers `[5573494, 5573567]' ? Or did you want long strings: `"55734945573567"` or a list of strings `["5573494", "5573567"]'  There is probably an easier way depending on what you want.

Comment: And will the numbers always be separated the same way? With two dots: `..`? And are there always exactly two numbers?

Comment: @rajah9 Yes, there are always 2 dots and numbers. I want both numbers separated in a list, which is what I'm getting now! But not sure why it isnt working. I know regex expressions may be easier but when I tried I couldnt figure out the pattern

Comment: You need to indent `print(m)` so that it's right under the `m = p.findall(line)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you'd like a list of strings returned from your function `extract_numbers`.

Python uses a powerful feature called Regular Expressions ([documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html)).

Here is an example in which all of the strings of one or more digits are extracted.

```
import re

line = "     tRNA            5573494..5573567"
p = re.compile('\d+') # \d means digit and + means one or more
m = p.findall(line)
m # returns ['5573494', '5573567']
```

Comment: Yes I tried to use regex expressions first but I couldn't figure out the pattern since the numerous tRNA tags in the file sometimes have complement in front of them and sometimes dont. There's usually around 40-50 tRNA tags in one file too

Comment: The pattern `\d+` will work (and won't care how many dots there are or how many characters precede). It will return the digit strings as separate number sequences. Here's where you can see it in action and try  out different strings: https://pythex.org/?regex=%5Cd%2B&test_string=%20%20%20%20%20tRNA%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%205573494..5573567&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0

Comment: Oh thanks! I've added an update to my question, but it isnt working? It is pulling out one occurrance: perhaps I need to put them in a list?

Comment: Please be more specific. What does it produce? ("But it isn't working" does not help; it forces me to re-do your entire program.)

Comment: Ah your solution fixed it!

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description of what you want to achieve, this should work. Note, `file.txt` is a sample that you included above:

```
import re

with open("file.txt") as f:
    data =f.readlines()
    
    numberList = []
    
    for line in data:
        dataList = line.split() #words separated by spaces split into list
        try: #if tRNA is not in line
            numberIndex = dataList.index("tRNA") + 1 # the numbers that are written after tRNA
            numberList.append(dataList[numberIndex])
        except Exception as _:
            continue

#The above cleans you data from all other numbers i.e "Tery_R0035"

#Taken from top answer (@rajah9)
p = re.compile('\d+') # \d means digit and + means one or more
for numData in numberList:
    m = p.findall(numData)
    print(m)
```

Comment: This could work! The problem I have is that each file has numerous tRNAs in them that I need to find and then get the numbers out

Comment: @Meems I've edited my answer to handle multiple instances of "tRNA"

Comment: thanks! This works partly, the issue I have is that it's pulling out all occurences of tRNA but I only need the ones at the start of the line! The output looks like this: 
`complement(42730..42801)
complement(68921..68995)
Synthetase"
158662..158734
158744..158826
complement(202341..202414)
complement(202420..202492)`
etc etc

Comment: I've edited my solution again to include reg exp (copied from @rajah9), how does the accepted solution handle numbers such as Tery_R0036?

Comment: For efficiency, I would move the re.compile step to precede the for loop. (It doesn't need to be recompiled for every line ; this just needs to happen once.)

Comment: @rajah9 now edited to include that improvement